# Redirecting with react-router in a react redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying to implement routing for my app which is built with react and redux. I have wrapped  in  so that route handlers can get access to the store.But somehow my routing logic is not working.

This piece of code was working fine

```js
export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.props.store}>
        <div>
          <App /> 
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

But when I replace with the below code it is not showhing anything on my localhost.

```js
export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.props.store}>
        <div>
        <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />

        </Router>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your project is browser based project. So , you can make use of `<BrowserRouter>` if your website/app is hosted on a dynamic server.
You can wrap it like :

```
    import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

    export default class Root extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={this.props.store}>
            <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />    
            <BrowserRouter>
            </div>
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }
```

if your web is backed by static server make use of `<HashRouter>`

You can read more [Here](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf)

Comment: Glad to help you out

Answer (score 2):

I think you're supposed to use one of the higher level router components like [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter). See if this works:

```
return (
  <Provider store={this.props.store}>
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </Provider>
);
```